# how to Search word in multiple files and show result without Duplicate paths in java?

Tags: java, android

i have code from Stack i just edited it to be able to search a word in Multiple files in path, but when i show the result in TextView i get get duplicated Paths (like the bellow picture), what i want is to get result as :

/example/path/to/folder/file1.txt
line 1 : word
line 2 : word
/example/path/to/folder/file2.txt
line 5 : word
line 13 : word

**and not like this :**

/example/path/to/folder/file1.txt
line 1 : word
/example/path/to/folder/file1.txt
line 5 : word
/example/path/to/folder/file1.txt
line 5 : word

[image]

this is my code :

```
textview1.setText(""); 
  
  File folder = new File("/sdcard/Alarms/");
   File[] brr = folder.listFiles();
  
  
  for (File f1 : brr) {
  
      String[] words=null;  
   
   try {
   
      FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);  
   
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
   
      String s;     
      String input="salut";   
   
      int count=0;   
  
      while((s=br.readLine())!=null)   
      {
         words=s.split(" ");  
   count++;
          for (String word : words) 
          {
                 if (word.equals(input))   
     
                 {
      
      
      textview1.append(f1.getPath()+"\n"+"line"+ " "+String.valueOf(count) + ": " + word + "\n");
                    
                 }
          }
      }
      if(count!=0)  
      {
         System.out.println("The given word is present for "+count+ " Times in the file");
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("The given word is not present in the file");
      }
      
         fr.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

any suggestion ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are counting the number of lines which have word and not the number of times a word appears in the file. You have two choices.

- if you want to count line containing multiple occurrences of word only once then you need to break in the if statement and display the text outside of for loop.
- if you want to count exact number of occurrences of word, you need to use a different counter for word occurrence and still display after if statement but increment count inside the if block.

E.g., one way to handle second case could be

```
    lIndex = 0;
    while((s=br.readLine())!=null) {
        wcount = 0;
        lIndex++; // line to check
        words = s.split(" ");  
        for (String word : words) {
            if (word.equals(input)) {
                // [one more] occurrence of word found
                wcount++;
            }
        }
        if (wcount > 0) {
            textview1.append(f1.getPath()+"\nline " + lIndex ": " + word + " occurs " + wcount + " times\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: give me small example brother I tried and I'm very confused, I'll be thankful if you give ma small example

Comment: I have added a small example, rest you should be able to figure out.

Comment: oh Thanks so much Brother, no i understand